# Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting, points to mongoose's openUri

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, jestjs

My `Express.js` app uses `mongoose` to access MongoDB. It uses `Jest v27` for unit test.

The `app.js` file `require`s the database module:

```
require('./modules/database/database');

exports.app = app;
```

The unit tests use this `app` for testing. Before any test is run, the `database.js` files connects to two databases. This file contains the following code fragment which is always run when the file is `require`-ed:

```
for (const url of urls) {
  const conn = mongoose.createConnection();

  //...

  // Establish connection
  conn.openUri(url, DatabasePrivate.connect_options);

  connections.push(conn);
}

// Wait for connections to complete establishment

(async () => {
  for (const connection of connections) {
    await connection;

    debug('Connection established to %O', connection.db.databaseName);
  }
})();
```

To close all connections, the `database.js` module has the following method in `Database` class:

```
class Database {
  //...
  static CloseConnections() {
    for (const connection of connections) {
      connection.close();
    }
  }
}
```

The tests are structured as follows:

```
const { app } = require('../app');
const { Database } = require('../modules/database/database');

describe('===== Some Tests ===== ', () => {

  afterAll(() => {
    Database.CloseConnections();
  });

  test('Version 2 - property check', async () => {
```

So even though I'm closing the connections, I'm still getting Jest's open handle error in the end:

```
Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

  ●  TLSWRAP

      57 |
      58 |   // Establish connection
    > 59 |   conn.openUri(url, DatabasePrivate.connect_options);
         |        ^
      60 |
      61 |   connections.push(conn);
      62 | }
```

I'm intentionally using `--detectOpenHandles` to catch this type of errors. So don't want to remove this flag.

How can I ensure that database connections are closed properly after unit tests completed running?